# bool for key in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a code like that

```
if ([dataArray valueForKey:@"success"]) {
    [self.feedsArray addObjectsFromArray:dataArray];
    NSLog(@"self.feedsArray: %@",self.feedsArray);
} else {
    NSLog(@"no feed found ");
}
```

`dataArray` is a `NSMutableArray` which ultimately contains a JSON Dictionary.

but I am getting the same console output independent of success either TRUE or FALSE, but my console output is always same.my console output is:

for FALSE or NO:

```
self.feedsArray: (
    {
        action = register;
        message = "Invalid parameters";
        success = 0;
    }
)
```

and for TRUE or YES:

```
self.feedsArray: (
    {
        action = register;
        message = "valid parameters";
        success = 1;
    }
)
```

in both cases if part is executed.

in NSUserDefaults there is a method `boolForKey` but how to do this in case of `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Use index instead of key for an array.

```
NSDictionary dictionary = (NSDictionary *)dataArray[0];
if ([(NSNumber *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: if ([(NSNumber *)[dataArray valueForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) {...} 

-[__NSArrayI boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x762e210
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x762e210'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16a5012 0x13b2e7e 0x17304bd 0x1694bbc 0x169494e 0xb3b9 0x24bd53f 0x24cf014 0x24bf7d5 0x164baf5 0x164af44 0x164ae1b 0x27067e3 0x2706668 0x2f6ffc 0x20ad 0x1fd5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Updated my answer. Use index for array instead of a key.

Comment: [[dataArray objectAtIndex:0] boolForKey:@"success"] is still crashing

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the fine print for [`[NSArray valueForKey:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey%3a), specifically:

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using
>   key on each of the array's objects.

and:

> The returned array contains NSNull elements for each object that
>   returns nil.

So if the array contains, say, 3 objects and none of them have a `success` key then you will get an array of 3 `NSNull` objects returned.

Therefore the `if` statement will *fire* whenever `dataArray` is non-empty, which is obviously not what you intended.

You should check the contents of the returned array:

```
BOOL succeeded = NO;
NSArray *results = [dataArray valueForKey:@"success"];
for (NSObject *obj in results) {
    succeeded = [obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [(NSNumber *)obj boolValue];
    if (succeeded)
        break;
}
if (succeeded) {
    [self.feedsArray addObjectsFromArray:dataArray];
    NSLog(@"self.feedsArray: %@",self.feedsArray);
} else {
    NSLog(@"no feed found ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in simple way:
What i see in your response json value is, you have dictionary in dataArray at index 0

```
 NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
 if([[responseDict objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue])
 {
      NSLog(@"Success: 1");
 }
 {
      NSLog(@"Success: 0");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

otherwise use `if([[[dataArray  objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"1"])`

Comment: How do you know it will be `@"1"`?

Comment: success may be either 1 or 0 na?

Comment: i used that app is crashing on this line

Comment: what is the crash log?

Comment: It will be "unrecognized selector sent to instance" for the obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

An array does not store keys, the only way to access items in an array is by index.
You should be using an NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary instead. If you want to use a bool store it as a NSNumber, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] and then use the instance method valueForBool to read it back.

Comment: No.  Check the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey:

Comment: It says
"Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects."
It returns an array, not a Boolean, for use with Key-Value coding. From the example shown, this doesn't look like what the OP needs.

Comment: Well the OP will have to clarify, but it looked to me to be exactly what he wanted.

Comment: Yep - not sure why you would perform "if" on an array, won't that always return true (assuming the array isn't nil itself)?

Comment: Yes; see my answer for how to correctly handle the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ([[dataArray valueForKey:@"success"]isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
     [self.feedsArray addObjectsFromArray:dataArray];
     NSLog(@"self.feedsArray: %@",self.feedsArray);
}
else {
     NSLog(@"no feed found ");
}
```

It 'll work out.

Comment: 2013-08-29 15:42:31.196 test[4375:c07] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8185d90
2013-08-29 15:42:31.197 test[4375:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8185d90'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16a5012 0x13b2e7e 0x17304bd 0x1694bbc 0x169494e 0xb3a1 0x24bd53f 0x24cf014 0x24bf7d5 0x164baf5 0x164af44 0x164ae1b 0x27067e3 0x2706668 0x2f6ffc 0x208d 0x1fb5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

use this if you want bool value

```
if([[dataArray valueForKey:@"success"] boolValue])
{
//i.e success is true 
}
```

if response contains array of dictionaries then we can use loop and check condition,
here i is index variable of array,

```
if([[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue])
{
// success is true , 
}
```

Comment: I already tried this and application is crashing with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you code line

```
 if ([dataArray valueForKey:@"success"]) {
}
```

with

```
 if ([[dataArray valueForKey:@"success"] integerValue]) {
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

its working with replacing the line with

```
if ([[[dataArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"success"] boolValue])
```